# How to interpret "$n" of ProGuard's mapping.txt?

Tags: android, proguard

A ProGuard's mapping.txt for an Android project is full of lines like the following:

```
...
net.domain.myapp.MyActivity$13 -> net.domain.myapp.dj:
...
net.domain.myapp.MyActivity$13$1 -> net.domain.myapp.dk:
...
net.domain.myapp.MyActivity$14 -> net.domain.myapp.dl:
...
```

I think MyActivity$n corresponds to a method of MyActivity, but I do not know how to map it to a specific  method.  I am wondering if anyone could offer a tip on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.example.Outer$Inner` is the internal naming convention in Java bytecode for an inner class `Inner` in the outer class `com.example.Outer`. You'll see it in stack traces, for instance, and you'll find the class file `com/example/Outer$Inner.class` between your compiled classes.

`com.example.Outer$1` is an anonymous inner class. The Java compiler assigns them sequential numbers.

At a bytecode level, inner classes aren't fundamentally different from other classes. ProGuard can treat them mostly the same.